# python regex multiple repeat at position 7

Tags: regex

```
url ='https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=United+Kingdom&rbl=London&jlid=833c779eabe84c9f'
ab = re.search(r"rbl=(.*+)",url)
print(ab.group(1) )
```

I am getting an error `re.error: multiple repeat at position 7`

Comment: Python 3. does not generate an error,  prints: London&jlid=833c779eabe84c9f

Answer (score -2):

Your code works fine with Python 3 and prints: `London&jlid=833c779eabe84c9f`
I replicated your "multiple repeat" error when running Python 2. I recommend just upgrading to the latest stable version of Python 3.